# How to limit and flip (exchange) elements of a string in php?

Tags: php, string, algorithm

I have a string which contains:

```
A1:B1:C1:D1,E1:F1:G1:H1
```

I want to remove everything expect:

```
A1:B1:C1
```

Afterwards I want to flip elements of the string around, in this case I want to flip the positions of `A1` and `C1` so `A1:B1:C1` becomes `C1:B1:A1`.

How would I be able to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried playing around with substr but it doesnt help in the second part of my question.

Comment: Well the add your attempt to your question and show us where you're stuck! (Do you have a pattern behind this to cut off or is it static 8 characters ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm:

> 1. Obtain the desire string
> 2. Obtain the tokens (A1, B1, C1)
> 3. Save in a temp var A1
> 4. Change the C1 value by A1
> 5. Change the C1 original position by temp
> 6. Make the string.

Code:

```
<?php

$string = 'A1:B1:C1:D1,E1:F1:G1:H1';

$less = substr($string, 0, 8);

$array = explode(':', $less);
$temp = $array[0];
$array[0] = $array[2];
$array[2] = $temp;

$final = implode(':', $array);

echo $final;
?>
```

Comment: Just for the future: With answering questions where OP doesn't show any effort/attempts that he may or may not made you are supporting low quality questions